# Import xls file with special character/image/sign

Tags: r

I have to read a xls file in R. But the problem is with special character/images.

There are around 10000 lines in my xls datafile, but it will read only upto 7000, from here only this special character(Key board Left Arrow sign appears.)
I don’t have any alternate options to convert xls/replace that special character.please help me out from this.
Your support highly appreciated

Data looks like:

```
   V1     V2      V3  
1.choco,Crack,Foodies  
2.choco,Crack,Foodies  
3.Flakes,Flakes,Foodies  
4.Flakes,Flakes,Foodies  
5.Flakes,Flakes,Foodies  
6.Surrain,Surrain,Tango->lilly  
7.Surrain,Surrain,Tango->lilly
```

My code:

```
read.xls(df.xls,sheet=1,blank.lines.skip=T,skip=2,header=F,strip.white=F,as.is=T)
```

output I got:

```
V1  V2  V3  
1.choco,Crack,Foodies  
2.choco,Crack,Foodies  
3.Flakes,Flakes,Foodies  
4.Flakes,Flakes,Foodies  
5.Flakes,Flakes,Foodies  
6.Surrain,Surrain,Tango
```

**Note:** Arrow sign between Tango Lilly is same as our left arrow key of keyboard

Comment: Have you tried `library(readxl); dat <- read_excel("file.xls")`?

Comment: You may also consider making use of the `XLConnect` package.

Comment: Should the arrow sign be replaced with a comma or should the arrow sign including lilly be removed altogether?

Comment: Thankyou David.I have tried read_excel.It works...There are some date variables are also included in my dataset,whose value get changed to numeric. How I can take care of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fread`.

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("//path/yourfile.xls",header=F, sep=",", na.string="NA")

head(dat)
```

The output, in which the whole string `"Tango->lilly"` is maintained, which of course can be changed.

```
 #          V1      V2           V3  
 #1:   1.choco   Crack      Foodies  
 #2:   2.choco   Crack      Foodies  
 #3:  3.Flakes  Flakes      Foodies  
 #4:  4.Flakes  Flakes      Foodies  
 #5:  5.Flakes  Flakes      Foodies  
 #6: 6.Surrain Surrain Tango->lilly
```